# How do I keep particles invisible until x seconds after they're emitted?

Tags: particles

I'm looking for a way to disable particle visibility for a certain period of time.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I would  recommend to clear up your question a bit with more details. It always helps to give an example with numbers to allow for an easier understanding of the situation you face. As your question looks more like 2 different **titles** for a question, i would recommend to use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/179287/edit) function and add some details of your situation instead of the one sentence. What you tried already, where you got stuck, a tutorial you may have followed. Maybe even a picture of the scene you work on. The clearer the better.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cycles, you can accomplish this by mixing with a Transparent shader depending on the Age output of the Particle Info node:

[image]